# Permission denied to tor hidden service directory on CentOS after service restart

Tags: centos, file-permissions, systemctl, tor

I have installed tor from EPEL on a fresh installed CentOS7 (minimal).

After configuring a hidden service I check and validate that the service is up and running by browsing the URL generated in `hostname` file from the tor browser.

At this point the service is configured to start automatically using `systemctl enable tor`

Everything works find until I restart the service `sudo systemctl restart tor`. After that tor service does not star anymore logging the following error:
`Directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service_01/ cannot be read: Permission denied`

`hidden_service_01` folder is automatically created by the tor service when it runs the first time.

if I delete `hidden_service_01` folder and start the service again. It starts up (generating a new .onion url). But once it's stopped and started again the permission error occurs again.

Why am I getting the permission error and how to I make it work?

P.S. I created a guide snippet the I used for my configuration:
https://gist.github.com/Dzoge/f059d30da77a21df1a0f29a0b5c528a2

**UPDATE 1:**
I have checked the folder permissions and they were:

- folder permissions are `rwx------. 2 toranon toranon`
- two files inside the folder are `rw-------. 1 toranon toranon`

I set `chmod` to `770` and now folder and files all have `rwxrwx---. 1 toranon toranon`

I try to start tor service `systemctl start tor` and still get the same permission warning.

**UPDATE 2:**
I tried doing the same on Ubuntu server and it worked pretty well. I updated the gist as well and added a guide for ubuntu.

The problem still remains with CentOS 7.

**UPDATE 3 (workaround):**
Looks like a temporary workaround is to set SELinux to permissive mode. Then it works as expected.

Comment: Do you have SElinux set to enforcing ? Are there any relevant avc denied messages in /var/log/audit/audit.log ?

Comment: Looks like it is a SELinux issue. When I set it to `permissive` it works well, but when it's in `enforcing` mode, then the problem occures.  `/var/log/audit/audit.log` shows the following errors: `avc:  denied  { dac_override }` and `avc:  denied  { dac_read_search }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the `tor.service` unit, you will see that it has a command to attempt to verify the Tor configuration before starting the service.

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/tor --runasdaemon 0 --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --verify-config
```

This is where things are going wrong. When this runs, the configuration fails to validate due to the permission problem noted earlier.

```
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP...
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran tor[28731]: Jan 06 16:18:42.650 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.14 (git-3f9bd01bf5736ff6) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips and Zlib 1.2.7.
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran tor[28731]: Jan 06 16:18:42.650 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran tor[28731]: Jan 06 16:18:42.650 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc".
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran tor[28731]: Jan 06 16:18:42.650 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran tor[28731]: Jan 06 16:18:42.653 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service_01/ cannot be read: Permission denied
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran tor[28731]: Jan 06 16:18:42.653 [warn] Checking service directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service_01/ failed.
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran tor[28731]: Jan 06 16:18:42.653 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran tor[28731]: Jan 06 16:18:42.653 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran systemd[1]: tor.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran systemd[1]: Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran systemd[1]: Unit tor.service entered failed state.
Jan 06 16:18:42 dalaran systemd[1]: tor.service failed.
```

Eventually I traced this down to some of the hardening that systemd does here. If you'll read further in the unit file, you'll see that systemd actually runs Tor in a container, and locks down the permissions very tightly. It also removes some capabilities, so that even root cannot do some actions the root user would normally be able to do, such as read other users' files (this is known as CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE).

When we attempt to audit the failed start, we find:

```
type=PATH msg=audit(1515277122.651:3600): item=0 name="/var/lib/tor/hidden_service_01/" inode=1054341 dev=fd:01 mode=040700 ouid=988 ogid=983 rdev=00:00 obj=system_u:object_r:tor_var_lib_t:s0 objtype=NORMAL
type=CWD msg=audit(1515277122.651:3600):  cwd="/"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1515277122.651:3600): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=561b6881af10 a1=20000 a2=0 a3=1 items=1 ppid=1 pid=28731 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="tor" exe="/usr/bin/tor" subj=system_u:system_r:tor_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1515277122.651:3600): avc:  denied  { dac_read_search } for  pid=28731 comm="tor" capability=2  scontext=system_u:system_r:tor_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:tor_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=AVC msg=audit(1515277122.651:3600): avc:  denied  { dac_override } for  pid=28731 comm="tor" capability=1  scontext=system_u:system_r:tor_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:tor_t:s0 tclass=capability
```

What I found here is that the command to verify config was not actually changing from the root user to the toranon user before reading the configuration, so access to the directory was being denied, as systemd did not give the process CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE. You can see the user IDs were logged as `uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0`.

So to resolve this on my system, I decided to have systemd start Tor as toranon rather than starting as root and Tor changing its own uid/gid.

1. I removed the `User toranon` setting from `/usr/share/tor/torrc-defaults`.
2. I created an override file `/etc/systemd/system/tor.service.d/override.conf` containing:

   ```
   [Service]
   User=toranon
   Group=toranon
   PermissionsStartOnly=no
   ```

It's necessary to use `PermissionsStartOnly=no` to ensure that the `ExecStartPre=` command is run under the toranon user. From the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#PermissionsStartOnly=):

> `PermissionsStartOnly=`
>   Takes a boolean argument. If true, the permission-related execution options, as configured with `User=` and similar options (see [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) for more information), are only applied to the process started with `ExecStart=`, and not to the various other `ExecStartPre=`, `ExecStartPost=`, `ExecReload=`, `ExecStop=`, and `ExecStopPost=` commands. If false, the setting is applied to all configured commands the same way. Defaults to false.

After a `systemctl daemon-reload` I was then able to `systemctl start tor` successfully.

```
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP...
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32030]: Jan 06 16:22:02.541 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.14 (git-3f9bd01bf5736ff6) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips and Zlib 1.2.7.
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32030]: Jan 06 16:22:02.541 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32030]: Jan 06 16:22:02.541 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc".
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32030]: Jan 06 16:22:02.541 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32030]: Configuration was valid
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32035]: Jan 06 16:22:02.665 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.14 (git-3f9bd01bf5736ff6) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips and Zlib 1.2.7.
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32035]: Jan 06 16:22:02.665 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32035]: Jan 06 16:22:02.665 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc".
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32035]: Jan 06 16:22:02.665 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32035]: Jan 06 16:22:02.668 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran tor[32035]: Jan 06 16:22:02.668 [notice] Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: OpenSSL version from headers does not match the version we're running with. If you get weird crashes, that might be why. (Compiled with 100020bf: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017; running wit
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Tor 0.2.9.14 (git-3f9bd01bf5736ff6) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips and Zlib 1.2.7.
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc".
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Jan 06 16:22:02 dalaran Tor[32035]: Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Jan 06 16:22:03 dalaran Tor[32035]: Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Jan 06 16:22:04 dalaran Tor[32035]: Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Jan 06 16:22:05 dalaran Tor[32035]: Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Jan 06 16:22:05 dalaran Tor[32035]: Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

Ultimately this (or something like it) needs to be incorporated into the Tor default config and systemd unit shipped by Fedora/EPEL, which will resolve the problem for everyone.

Comment: Great! This fixed the problem for me and SELinux is still enabled.